# Manually Setting currentTarget with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I'm consistently having a problem with React / Javascript: often times, I want to anchor something on the close of a modal.

**Example**

1. Some modal is triggered, for example, "Would you like to do this or
   that?", with *this* and *that* each being a button.
2. When the user clicks, *this*, the modal holding that button closes and causes another DOM element that requires an anchor (in my case, it's a `<Popover/>` component.

**Expected Behavior**
The popover component is rendered where the *this* button was clicked, enabling further action from the user.

**Observed Behavior**
The popover component is still rendered, but an error is thrown in the console indicating that the anchor element is undefined.

I know that what's going on here is that the modal with the *this* and *that* buttons has now closed, so the `Popover` has nothing to anchor to. So, I'm wondering if there's an approach that would enable me to close the initial modal with the *this* and *that* buttons while still anchoring to the spot where one of the buttons was clicked. That's why I've titled this "manually setting currentTarget", because I'm wondering if there's a way to *create* this anchor or something like that.

Thanks for your help,

Davis

Comment: No, you will not achieve this by messing with the event (or its `currentTarget`) in any way. (Or, you might, but it won't be straightforward).

Comment: What do you mean by "anchor" specifically? Attach to the DOM as a child? Show in the same position on page?

Comment: @Bergi some component, like a <Popover> need to be "anchored" to some place in the DOM. It basically determines where the popover appears on the page.